# Apex Report Flash Charts In Emails

Tags: flash, email, pdf-generation, report, oracle-apex

My Oracle Apex application gives the user the ability to **email a customized report**. **The report consists of a flash chart and a data table**. I am currently doing this by constructing the HTML for the page programmatically and injecting that into an email.

I cannot send charts this way though as almost all **email clients do not support flash**. This makes the report less appealing.

Is there a way to render these apex report pages (both flash chart and the table) as pdf on the server side , so that this can be sent as an attachment by email.

**Are there any existing APEX plugins or widgets (preferred) that will help facilitate this ?** The application has been developed **using Oracle Apex 4.0**.

If the above is not possible **are there any open source or paid software in the market that will get this job done ?**

Appreciate your comments and suggestions !!  Thanks !!

Comment: Yes, APEX charting in Flash is Anychart. You can use RenderX XEP software with their RichMedia extension to embed the Anychart Flash and data into the document. We have actually done this before. See http://public.tandesa.com/Xportability/Services/Multimedia/RenderX_Funds.pdf  you can contact me for details (note, to view you must use PDF viewer that supports Flash, not pdf.js or Chrome or Firefox ... Adobe Plug-in is required.

Comment: As an additional note, we have also built APEX to RenderX XEP through RenderX's Web Services interface.

Comment: This takes care of converting & viewing the pdf. Would i be able to get apex to email the pdf too ? Thanks !!

Comment: APEX_MAIL, I have not integrated that into an application before but I see no reason why it would not work. The biggest issues you hit in such an application is properly writing the PL/SQL to handle clobs to overcome limitations in size. Here's a simple test bed the is APEX report through RenderX to deliver back PDF. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=79509:4:0::NO:::

Comment: You could also store PDFs in the cloud or in Oracle and serve only links. That said, APEX_MAIL supports file attachments so I would think you would be good to go either way.

Comment: Note: That link above will likely not work for you, I forgot the security issues. You would need to be logged into APEX so contact privately if you wish to test.

Comment: Yup , even sending the report as an email attachment would be fine. Sounds like a neat solution. Will give it a try. Thanks !!